# Writing and Reading by HC 05

Tags: bluetooth

I am writing a project that transmits temperature between 2 Arduino controllers(wemos D1)
Via Bluetooth HC 05.
I set up Module 1 as a master
and Module 2 as a slave.
I want to transmit the temperature.
temp sensor DS1820 conect to  controler 1(Master) .
i want read  the temp value in controller 2 (slave) via Bluetooth and show in
Sariel Monitor contriler 2.
I've tried a lot of ways but can't......
I would be very happy for help
And even an example of code that works (master & slave).
Thank you
hezi

I can't send and receive value

Comment: Please provide at lease one option you've attempted in your question. Please post code using the appropriate formatting, not as an image.